# Split mysql query and delete a part of that

Tags: php, mysql

I have many conditions in PHP function which every of them produces a mysql query.All conditions work correctly except one query which ends with `AND` operator.Before returning the query result I need to check if query ends with `AND` it should remove `AND` and then returnes the query.
This is the sample of query:

```
$query="select * from case where case_name='name' AND case_status='102' AND";
```

If this kind of query is produced I need to do:
1-If it ends with `AND`
2-remove `AND`
3-return the query without last `AND`
The result should be like this:

```
$query="select * from case where case_name='name' AND case_status='102' ";
```

I do not have much experience to work with PHP functions.How can I do this?
Thnaks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`$query="select * from case where case_name='name' AND case_status='102' AND"
$query = trim($query,'AND');`

Answer (score 0):

quick fix:

```
$query = preg_replace( "/AND$/",  "", $query);
```

You should fix the logic of condition though.
like

```
$cond[] = "....";
$cond[] = "...."
....
```

then

```
$query = $query_first_half +  implode ( " AND " , $cond );
```

Ultimately please use sql library like PDO

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

explode the string and pop the last element .

```
$arr = explode(" ", $query);

$last = array_pop($arr);
if($last != "and")
{
  array_push($arr,$last);
}
$query = implode(" ",$arr);
```

Run the $query them it should work

Answer (score 0):

- First your table name `CASE` is mysql [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) you should rename your table to something else or escpae it by backticks `
- you could use query without AND , and when you add other query just start by AND .

like that :

```
  $query="select * from `case` where case_name='name' AND case_status='102'";  
  $query .= " AND .........";
```

so like that , your condition is not true then just first query will work , if condition is true then second query will work and it start by AND. You dont need to remove the AND.

Comment: my table name is forensic_case it was my mistake to write 'case'.According to my code I need to remove AND.

Comment: Read my second point, you need to make your first query without AND . and second which you will add it just start by AND. look example how to do it.